# Round Date() milliseconds

Tags: javascript

Hello I want to round my `Date()` variable to 3 digits after seconds, example below:

The initial value: `2012-08-29T21:28:28.8789063+03:00`
The value I want to achieve: `2012-08-29T21:28:28.88`

Or if I can't really do this, I want to remove 10 chars starting from end, if so how could I do that?

Comment: very similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914020/javascript-date-to-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the substring or substr function and take 10 characters off from the length

Answer (score 0):

I use the [jQuery dateFormat plugin](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat) to format dates.

To just strip off the last 10 chars, try:

```
date = dateObj.toString();
formattedDate = date.substr(0, date.length-10);
```