# How to get hh:mm:ss from date object?

Tags: javascript, date

How can I get this hh:mm:ss from date object?

```
var d = new Date(); // for now
datetext = d.getHours()+":"+d.getMinutes()+":"+d.getSeconds();
```

I get this result below sometimes,

```
12:10:1
```

which should be

```
12:10:01
```

I assume this happens to the hour and minute as well.

So I am after this

```
01:01:01
```

Not this 1:1:1

Comment: How about testing whether each value is less than 10 and prepending a zero?

Comment: yes you are right - good thinking!

Comment: Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914020/javascript-date-to-string

Answer (score 81, accepted):

**Solution - (tl;dr version)**

`datetext = d.toTimeString().split(' ')[0]`

**Explanation:**

`toTimeString` returns the complete time.
We split it by space to get the time component only, then take the first value which is of use. :)

Complete Flow:

```
d = new Date();
// d is "Sun Oct 13 2013 20:32:01 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
datetext = d.toTimeString();
// datestring is "20:32:01 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
// Split with ' ' and we get: ["20:32:01", "GMT+0530", "(India", "Standard", "Time)"]
// Take the first value from array :)
datetext = datetext.split(' ')[0];
```

**Note:** This does not require you to include any external files or libraries hence time required for *execution would be faster.*

Comment: Thanks man, for short and sweet solution. :)

Comment: >>datetext = datetext.split(' ')[0];

This return "20:32:01", is it possible to only HH:MM and not HH:MM:SS ? @sunny-r-gupta

Comment: @adi , sure, once you have HH:MM:SS, simply drop the last 3 ‍♂️

Answer (score 19):

I'd suggest you to checkout some date/time library. [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is one good example.

You could do simply as below

```
var d = new Date();
var formatteddatestr = moment(d).format('hh:mm:ss a');
```

Here is an [example from fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kkk6Q/5/)

Comment: That fiddle gave me "04:07:37 pm" instead of the "16:07:37" requested in the question.

Comment: I suggest you go through the documentation. Sure you can manipulate the way you want if you change the formatter.

Comment: Try HH instead of hh for 24h times.

Comment: 'a' gives am/pm. 'A' will give AM/PM

Answer (score 16):

You can use this code snippet. I also added it to [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/KwXMh/5/) and added type-safer comments, so make sure to check out the fiddle.

If you're using jQuery, call it within your ready function. Otherwise you could use plain JavaScript to update the value of your field.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var d = new Date();
    var formatted_time = time_format(d);
    $('#yourTimeField').text(formatted_time);
});
```

Add these two methods to your script (you could also paste it in a single file, like it is in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KwXMh/5/) code snippet):

```
function time_format(d) {
    hours = format_two_digits(d.getHours());
    minutes = format_two_digits(d.getMinutes());
    seconds = format_two_digits(d.getSeconds());
    return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}

function format_two_digits(n) {
    return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n;
}
```

That's it :) Hope it helps :)

Comment: I prefer this answer rather than the accepted one because here you are using real hours, minutes and seconds instead to "blind trim" the string.

Comment: Just be vary that by `minutes =` you are setting minutes inside global namespace, I think that `var minutes =` would be better (or `const minutes =` in ES6).

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using http://momentjs.com/. A javascript date library for parsing, validating, manipulating, and formatting dates.