# How to set user-defined time in Javascript and add 2 hours to it?

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

The user is providing time in the format of 12:00:00 (which is in string), and I want to add 1 or 3 hours to the time and show it as the end time.

The code:

```
function showCart(cart) {
  
  for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
    var slotHtmlTr = '';
    var c = i + 1;
    slotHtmlTr += '<tr style="border: 1px solid black;" id="slot'+c+'">';
    slotHtmlTr += '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">Slot '+c+'</td>';
    slotHtmlTr += '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">'+cart[i].from_date+'</td>';
    slotHtmlTr += '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">'+cart[i].start_time+'</td>';
    slotHtmlTr += '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">End Time here</td>';
    slotHtmlTr += '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">'+cart[i].room_id+'</td>';
    slotHtmlTr += '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">'+cart[i].duration+'</td>';
    var slotPrice = (cart[i].duration == "1") ? 15 : 30;
    slotHtmlTr += '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">'+slotPrice+ '</td>';
    slotHtmlTr += '</tr>';
  }
  $('#slotsDetails').append(slotHtmlTr);
  // console.log(slotHtml);
}
```

How I am adding the time:

```
let hrsAdd = 3;
let start_time = cart[i].start_time;
let end_time = new Date(start_time); //showing some error
console.log(end_time + hrsAdd);
```

I know I am doing something wrong, but can't figure out what?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse a time into a Date object from user input in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141348/how-to-parse-a-time-into-a-date-object-from-user-input-in-javascript)

Comment: do not forget that time can move you to the next day (*adding 3 hours to 11pm should go to 2am, but in the next day. do you account for day changes ?*)

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli No, not for day changes. only time.

Comment: @HereticMonkey No it does not. I tried but I want only time like 12:00:00 not GMT, date, and all.

Comment: Then why are you using `new Date(start_time)`? The `Date` object allows you to add hours to the datetime value, then format it as the time portion ([jquery: How to get hh:mm:ss from date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19346405/215552)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remember that Date class has some limitation on creating it, so you may not just set your time on the constructor, it must be in a specific format. For more details take a look on the JS [Date class documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Your time calculation can be done with a similar code to this:

```
srcTime = "12:01:02"; // value sent by the user
baseDateTime = new Date(); // the date does not matter to us, but it comes together as it is the Date class
[srcHour, srcMinute, srcSecond] = srcTime.split(":"); // we separate the value in the right variables
baseDateTime.setHours(parseInt(srcHour) + 3); // update the Date object with user hour + 3 hours

// from this point on you can work with the baseDateTime variable to extract the time, date and etc.
// for example:
end_time = baseDateTime.getHours() + ":" + baseDateTime.getMinutes() + ":" + baseDateTime.getSeconds();
```

Comment: Worked liked charm!