# How to merge two objects with same property in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, object

I have a JSON Data like this:

```
"Data": [
            {
                "time": "18:40:43",
                "count": 7,
                "endTime": "15:46:25",
                "date": "2019-01-16",
                "dow": "Thursday"
            },
            {
                "count": 11,
                "time": "16:39:52",
                "endTime": "19:41:03",
                "dow": "Thursday",
                "date": "2019-01-16"
            },
]
```

I want to merge two objects in this array, but it have same properties like `date`, `dow`

at the end I want to represent data like this:

```
"Data": [
            {
                "time": "16:39:52",
                "count": 18,
                "date": "2019-01-16",
                "dow": "Thursday"
                "endTime": "19:41:03",
            },
]
```

`time`: should be least from both objects and `endTime` should be largest of both of them
`count` should be sum of both. `date` and `dow` is common in both objects

How can I merge these object in this way in node JS?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please update the questions with relavent details regarding what you have attempted? where you are stuck etc.

Comment: **"Data"** will have only 2 arrays or its n number of arrays??

Comment: @gcodess: it has `n` number of objects but, there are no arrays inside it

Comment: use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)?

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggested solutions?
Is there any useful solution or solution you can mark as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data=[
            {
                "time": "18:40:43",
                "count": 7,
                "endTime": "15:46:25",
                "date": "2019-01-16",
                "dow": "Thursday"
            },
            {
                "count": 11,
                "time": "16:39:52",
                "endTime": "19:41:03",
                "dow": "Thursday",
                "date": "2019-01-16"
            },
];
let date=(time)=>new Date().setHours(...time.split(":"));

let newData=[];
data.forEach((item)=>{
  let findItem=newData.findIndex((e)=>e.date===item.date && e.dow===item.dow);
  if(findItem!=-1){
  let find=data.filter((e)=>e.dow===item.dow && e.date===item.date);
  let time=find.filter((i)=>find.find(i2=>date(i2.time)>date(i.time)));
    let endTime=find.filter((i)=>find.find(i2=>date(i2.endTime)<date(i.endTime)));
  item.endTime=endTime?.[0]?.endTime || item?.endTime;
  item.time=time?.[0]?.time || item?.time;
  item.count=find.map((e)=>e.count).reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + a, 0);
   let findItem=newData.findIndex((e)=>e.date===item.date && e.dow===item.dow);
   if(findItem!=-1) newData.splice(findItem,1);
   newData.push(item);
  }

 else newData.push(item);
});
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple and readable answer:

```
const data = [
  {
    time: "18:40:43",
    count: 7,
    endTime: "15:46:25",
    date: "2019-01-16",
    dow: "Thursday",
  },
  {
    count: 11,
    time: "16:39:52",
    endTime: "19:41:03",
    dow: "Thursday",
    date: "2019-01-16",
  },
];
const mergeObjects = (data) => {
  mergedObj = { ...data[0] };
  for (i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    const obj = data[i];
    for (const key in obj) {
      switch (key) {
        case "count":
          mergedObj.count = (mergedObj.count || 0) + obj.count;
        case "time":
          mergedObj.time =
            mergedObj.time < obj.time ? mergeObjects.time : obj.time;
        case "endTime":
          mergedObj.endTime = mergedObj.endTime > obj.endTime ? mergeObjects.endTime : obj.endTime;
      }
    }
  }
  return mergedObj;
};

console.log(mergeObjects(data));
```

### output

```
{
    "time": "16:39:52",
    "count": 18,
    "date": "2019-01-16",
    "dow": "Thursday"
    "endTime": "19:41:03",
},
```

Comment: If there is an object that doesn't have same propertied I don't want to merge with other objects, and put it in as a seperate object in the same array then what should I do?

Comment: @santosh-kumar In this case, please ask the question with actual input/output data without any ifs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

- "Data" would have only two objects inside it
- time would be in "HH::MM::SS" format

Pass the values onto **constructJSON** utility function which would return the formatted value

```js
var Data = [
            {
                "time": "18:40:43",
                "count": 7,
                "endTime": "15:46:25",
                "date": "2019-01-16",
                "dow": "Thursday"
            },
            {
                "count": 11,
                "time": "16:39:52",
                "endTime": "19:41:03",
                "dow": "Thursday",
                "date": "2019-01-16"
            },
]


function constructJSON(data)
{
 const returnData = {}
 returnData['count'] = data[0].count + data[1].count
 returnData['date'] = data[0].date    // since its common for both
 returnData['dow'] = data[0].dow      // since its common for both
 returnData['time'] = parseInt(data[0].time.split(':').join(''),10) < parseInt(data[1].time.split(':').join(''),10) ? data[0].time:data[1].time;
  returnData['endTime'] = parseInt(data[0].endTime.split(':').join(''),10) > parseInt(data[1].endTime.split(':').join(''),10) ? data[0].endTime:data[1].endTime;
 
  return returnData
}

console.log(constructJSON(Data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of merging - all keys are combined, the common keys are overwritten by the second object, but `count`, `time` and `endTime` are calculated by special conditions

```js
const 
   data = [{"time": "18:40:43","count": 7,"endTime": "15:46:25","date": "2019-01-16","dow": "Thursday"},{"count": 11,"time": "16:39:52","endTime": "19:41:03","dow": "Thursday","date": "2019-01-16"}],

  [first, last] = data,
  dumbDate = '2000-01-01 ',

  result = {
    ...first,
    ...last,
    count: first.count + last.count,
    time: (new Date(`${dumbDate}${first.time}`) < new Date(`${dumbDate}${last.time}`)) ? first.time : last.time,
    endTime: (new Date(`${dumbDate}${first.endTime}`) > new Date(`${dumbDate}${last.endTime}`)) ? first.endTime : last.endTime,
};

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), you should be able to do this pretty easily, it should also expand to let you expand with more than just 2 objects in the array.

```js
const data = [{
    "time": "18:40:43",
    "count": 7,
    "endTime": "15:46:25",
    "date": "2019-01-16",
    "dow": "Thursday"
  },
  {
    "count": 11,
    "time": "16:39:52",
    "endTime": "19:41:03",
    "dow": "Thursday",
    "date": "2019-01-16"
  },
];

//res will contain the output
const res = data.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
    
  //Initially the accumulator will be null
  if (!acc) return curr;
  
  //Add the counts up
  acc.count += curr.count;

  //Convert both times into dates and find the minimum
  const accTime = new Date(acc.date + 'T' + acc.time); //We add the T here since that's just how the Date constructor accepts times
  const currTime = new Date(acc.date + 'T' + curr.time);
  acc.time = new Date(Math.min(accTime, currTime)).toTimeString().split(' ')[0]; //See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19346405/how-to-get-hhmmss-from-date-object

  //Do the same for the end times but find the maximum
  const accEndTime = new Date(acc.date + 'T' + acc.endTime);
  const currEndTime = new Date(acc.date + 'T' + curr.endTime);
  acc.endTime = new Date(Math.max(accEndTime, currEndTime)).toTimeString().split(' ')[0];
  return acc;
});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array#reduce()` and `Array#map()` methods as follows:

```js
const data = {"Data": [{"time": "18:40:43", "count": 7, "endTime": "15:46:25", "date": "2019-01-16", "dow": "Thursday"}, {"count": 11, "time": "16:39:52", "endTime": "19:41:03", "dow": "Thursday", "date": "2019-01-16" }]};

const newD = {Data:data.Data.reduce(
    (prev,{date,dow,count,...r}) => 
        //check if an element in array prev has dow & date props equal to the current element
        prev.findIndex(p => p.date === date && p.dow === dow) > -1 ? 
            //If found process the matching element
            prev.map(({date:d,dow:w,count:c,...rs}) => 
                d === date && w === dow ? 
                ({...rs,date:d,dow:w,count:c+count,time:rs.time < r.time ? rs.time : r.time,endTime:rs.endTime > r.endTime ? rs.endTime : r.endTime}) : 
                ({...rs,date:d,dow:w,count:c})
            ) : 
            //If not add the current element to array prev
            prev.concat({...r,date,dow,count}), 
            //start off with an empty array
            []
)};

console.log( newD );
```