# Javascript getDate()and getMonth() return wrong result

Tags: javascript, date, getdate

I create a new Date object, using timestamp. If I print out that object, it returns correct date and time. But if I try to use getDate()and getTime(), they get me back wrong numbers.

My code:

```
var textDate = new Date(timestamp);

console.log(timestamp);
console.log(textDate);  
console.log(textDate.getDate(),textDate.getMonth(),textDate.getFullYear());
```

My console result:

```
1476483081000
Date 2016-10-14T22:11:21.000Z
15 9 2016
```

How can I get correct date and month from textDate variable?

Comment: You are getting the correct numbers, months are zero based, so october would actually be `9`, and the date is probably adjusted for timezone

Comment: Duplicate:[javascript date to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914020/javascript-date-to-string)

Comment: Month is correct. The problem with date was resolved after I use getUTCDate() and getUTCHours(). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The getMonth() method returns the month from 0 to 11.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

When you print the date, it relies on the timezone. If you are in a timezone 2 hours away from GMT, then the 22:11 might shift to a new day, this is probably why getDate() returns the dext day.

Comment: There was a problem with timezone. Resolved with getUTCDate(). Thanks!

Comment: If the timezone is bothering you, remove it from your timestamp initially: `new Date(timestamp - new Date().getTimezoneOffset())`